# React js createRef() returning undefined

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am very new to reactjs. Currently developing mobile app using ReactJS native by using expo.io. In my project, I am using the webView to display the content. It works fine. But I get a problem when I try to implemented the goBack().

The example that I have followed:
https://blog.defining.tech/adding-a-back-button-for-react-native-webview-4a6fa9cd0b0

Since this.refs is depreciated, I try to change it to createRef()
Another ref. that I followed:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-class-component

When goBack() is executed, 'undefined is not an object' is flowed.

May I know solution for this?

Here is my code:

```
enter code here
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  WebView
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.webRef = React.createRef();     
    this.state = { canGoBack: false };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          ref={this.webRef}
          style={{flex: 1}}
          onNavigationStateChange=
            {this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
          source={{uri: 'http://www.google.com'}}
          /> 
          <View style={styles.bottombar}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            disabled={!this.state.canGoBack}
            onPress={this.onBack.bind(this)}
            >
            <Text style={this.state.canGoBack ? styles.topbarText : styles.topbarTextDisabled}>Go Back</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  onBack() {
    // error: undefined is not an object 
    this.webRef.current.goBack();
  }


  onNavigationStateChange(navState) {
    this.setState({
      canGoBack: navState.canGoBack
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the ref is undefined but `this.webRef.current` is undefined.

You can just use `this.webRef.goBack()`